# Updating an array in a 2D array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I created a 2D array `A`:

```
A = [A_0, A_1, ... A_n]
```

and appended `A_n` to `A`, which now makes it:

```
A = [A_0, A_1, ... A_n, A_n]
```

Then I attempted to change an element in the last array, expecting to get:

```
A = [A_0, A_1, ... A_n, A_n'] # (the last array is changed)
```

However, I get this:

```
A = [A_0, A_1, ... A_n', A_n'] # (two last arrays are changed)
```

It's like the two `A_n`s share the same index.

Example code:

```
arr = [[0], [0]]
arr << arr[1]    
p arr
arr[1][0] = 1
p arr
```

Expected output:

```
[[0], [0], [0]]  
[[0], [1], [0]]
```

Actual output:

```
[[0], [0], [0]]  
[[0], [1], [1]]
```

Why is this, how do I bypass it?

Comment: When you do `arr << arr[1]` Ruby does not insert a *copy* of `arr[1]`. It actually inserts a references to `arr[1]`. Try, `arr << arr[1].dup`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints. The more effort you put into your question, the more likely people are to help you.

Comment: `A` is a constant in Ruby. You need to use lower-case variable names. `A_n'` isn't valid in code, so for your examples please use valid array and variables otherwise we have to spend too much time fixing your syntax errors before we can actually help the real problem.

Comment: @theTinMan The example code is valid,  however I made the mistake of describing the problem without consideration of the specified language.
Thanks for editing (and for the link)!

Comment: @lurker Thanks, this works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're seeing is due to the array being the same object in index 1 as index 2. To see this, run `arr.map(&:object_id)`, you can bypass it by duplicating array being pushed in like so:

```
arr = [[0], [0]]
arr << arr[1].dup    
p arr
#=> [[0],[0],[0]]
arr[1][0] = 1
p arr
#=> [[0],[1],[0]]
```

Comment: Use `object_id` to show they're the same. It'll make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you visualize the problem:

```
arr = [[0], [0]]
arr.map{ |o| o.object_id.to_s(16) } # => ["3fd87c4e2854", "3fd87c4e2840"]
```

Those are the object IDs for the two elements in the array.

```
arr << arr[1]    
arr.map{ |o| o.object_id.to_s(16) } # => ["3fd87c4e2854", "3fd87c4e2840", "3fd87c4e2840"]
```

If you append the second element back to the array, you're going to get a duplicate of it, so changing that element will be reflected in both references to it.

If instead you append an empty array, you'd have created a new object, as evidenced by the different `object_id`:

```
arr = [[0], [0]]
arr << []
arr.map{ |o| o.object_id.to_s(16) } # => ["3ff8110dfe28", "3ff8110dfe14", "3ff8110dfdec"]
```

The `object_id` values for the elements changed because that was a separate run of the expressions. The important thing is now all three have separate IDs.